# Spark submit not respecting spark.driver.supervise=true set in spark-defaults.conf

Tags: apache-spark, livy

#### What issue I faced?

- I specified `spark.driver.supervise=true` in spark-defaults.conf
- `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit` script did not pick this configuration. It started job/driver with `spark.driver.supervise=false`
- PS: So far I have only found `spark.driver.supervise` property not working via spark-defaults.conf way. Other properties that I am using are working perfectly fine.

#### How to reproduce the issue?

- Add `spark.driver.supervise=true` OR `spark.driver.supervise  true` in spark-defaults.conf
- Submit a spark application using `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit` script
- The job/driver will NOT be running in supervision mode. To check this, goto `<DRIVER_URL>:4040/environment/` and check for `spark.driver.supervise` property

#### What was I expecting?

- I was hoping that by default, even when I do not pass `--supervise` argument explicitly to spark-submit command, it should have picked up the same from spark-defaults.conf
- I got this understanding of specifying default spark properties in spark-defaults.conf by reading the spark configuration [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties).

#### What makes this issue important?

- Apache Livy is a REST client that helps submit spark jobs via HTTP requests.
- Livy is used by so many organizations and AWS EMR, Cloudera uses Livy under the hood.
- Livy internally invokes `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit` shell script.
- As per Livy's [code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/server/src/main/scala/org/apache/livy/utils/SparkProcessBuilder.scala), there is no way to specify supervise option

#### An ugly hack to make Livy/spark-submit work in supervision mode by default

- open `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit` in shell editor
- change line `exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit "$@"` TO **`exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit "--supervise" "$@"`**
- Notice the extra shell argument in double quotes `"--supervise"`. This does the trick and Livy/spark-submit works.

Comment: You still can try to pass it with `..., "conf": { "spark.driver.supervise": true }, ...` in the POST request body. Can you check if it works that way? Also note that by Spark docs this config `Only has effect in Spark standalone mode or Mesos cluster deploy mode`, for which Livy support is limited.

Comment: I have tried specifying it in the Livy POST body's conf part. It did not work. I then checked Livy's [source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/server/src/main/scala/org/apache/livy/utils/SparkProcessBuilder.scala) and found that they have not handled the case of `spark.driver.supervise`. Ideally, Livy should have a code that will check if `spark.driver.supervise` is set as true in POST params conf part and if yes then they should append `--supervise` when invoking smark-submit command/script. And yes, I am using spark standalone cluster mode.

Comment: Now let's think only from the `spark-submit`'s perspective. As per spark config [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties), they support `spark.driver.supervise` config to be added in spark-defaults.conf. So, if what config doc is saying is true, then it should have worked when invoking `spark-submit` command/script from CLI manually. Even without me specifying `--supervise` args, spark-submit should have picked it up from spark-defaults.conf. So, either there is a bug in spark code OR my understanding is wrong. Someone, please educate me more on this

Comment: I've checked the [Livy code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/blob/master/server/src/main/scala/org/apache/livy/utils/SparkProcessBuilder.scala#L183-L184) - it sets all the `conf` values with the builder. So I feel that somewhere `SparkSubmit` flow overrides the `--conf spark.driver.supervise`. Will try to debug that a bit later. Can you share the Spark/Livy versions you use? And have you made any customizations?

Comment: Spark version = 2.4.4, Hadoop version = 3.1.3, Livy version = 0.6.0. The only customization that I did is that I am NOT using the "spark-and-hadoop" bundled package. I have downloaded `spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop.tgz` and `hadoop-3.1.3.tar.gz` separately and using it by specifying `export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$({{hadoop.install_dir}}/bin/hadoop classpath)`

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am trying to tell spark to use VLAN-correct interfaces and nothing I set in `spark-env.sh` or `spark-defaults.conf` seems to be taking.